# C# - Running Total using Aggregate()

Tags: c#, extension-methods

This question was asked at interview.I need to have running total (**only using Aggregate()** )

from array

(i.e)

```
int[] array={10,20,30};

Expected output

10
30
60
```

when i use Aggregate (**I applied some worst logic**)

```
array.Aggregate((a, b) => { Console.WriteLine(a + b); return (a + b); });
```

1) `It prints 30,60` ,for me there is no use of return (a+b).

2) In order to print `10` , i have to modify the array by adding element zero
   (i.e) {0,10,20,30}.

Is there any neat work could turn it out?

Comment: Whomever asked you to do that does not use good coding practices for sequence operators. "Aggregate" should return a scalar value, and that's all it should do; it should not produce a side effect along the way.  If what you want to produce is "sequence of accumulated running totals" then don't use Aggregate; write a new sequence operator "Accumulate" and use that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try `array.Aggregate(0, (a, b) => { Console.WriteLine(a + b); return (a + b); });` instead :-)

Answer (score 2):

`Aggregate` has other overloads that work slightly differently -- take a look at this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218.aspx:

```
public static TAccumulate Aggregate<TSource, TAccumulate>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    TAccumulate seed,
    Func<TAccumulate, TSource, TAccumulate> func )
```

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the seed-value as 0:

```
int[] array = { 10, 20, 30 };
array.Aggregate(0, (a, b) => { Console.WriteLine(a + b); return a + b; });
```

This will output what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

```
array.Aggregate(0, (a, b) => 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(a + b); 
    return a + b;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array.Aggregate(0, (progress, next) => { Console.WriteLine(progress + next); return (progress + next); });
```

Use the version of Aggregate that starts aggregating with a seed value, rather than that starts aggregating with the first pair.